# Mathematica: Tangent of Two Curves

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I asked this question yesterday but not sure if I made clear what I was looking for. Say I have two curves defined as `f[x_]:=...` and `g[x_]:=...` as shown below. I want to use Mathematica to determine the abscissa intersection of the tangent to both curves and store value for each curve separately. Perhaps this is really a trivial task, but I do appreciate the help. I am an intermediate with Mathematica but this is one I haven't been able to find a solution to elsewhere.

[image]

Comment: What's the link to the question you asked yesterday?

Comment: I deleted it, because it is was clearly ill defined and there were a lot of derogatory comments

Comment: These curves fold back on themselves; I presume they are parametric?  Why not include actual definitions in your question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think they're freehand :)

Comment: @yoda I guessed as much myself, but if you allow such curves it is going to greatly change the answer, is it not?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Will depend on the curves, for sure, but not necessarily because they fold back... e.g., two circles

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := (x - 2)^2 + 3

sol = Solve[(f[x1] - g[x2])/(x1 - x2) == f'[x1] == g'[x2], {x1, x2}, Reals]

(* ==> {{x1 -> 3/4, x2 -> 11/4}} *)

eqns = FlattenAt[{f[x], g[x], f'[x1] x + g[x2] - f'[x1] x2 /. sol}, 3]; 
Plot[eqns, {x, -2, 4}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

Please note that there will be many functions `f` and `g` for which you won't find a solution in this way. In that case you will have to resort to numerical problem solving methods.

Answer (score 2):

You just need so solve a system of simultaneous equations:

The common tangent line is `y = a x + b`.

The common slope is `a = f'(x1) = g'(x2)`

The common points are `a x0 + b = f(x0)` and `a x1 + b = g(x1)`.

Depending on the nature of the functions `f` and `g` this may have no, one, or many solutions.