# Mathematica: FindRoot for common tangent

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592200/mathematica-tangent-of-two-curves) a little while back that did help in reaching a solution. I've arrived at a somewhat acceptable approach but still not fully where I want it. Suppose there are two functions `f1[x]` and `g1[y]` that I want to determine the value of `x` and `y` for the common tangent(s). I can at least determine `x` and `y` for one of the tangents for example with the following:

```
f1[x_]:=(5513.12-39931.8x+23307.5x^2+(-32426.6+75662.x-43235.4x^2)Log[(1.-1.33333x)/(1.-1.x)]+x(-10808.9+10808.9x)Log[x/(1.-1.x)])/(-1.+x)
g1[y_]:=(3632.71+3806.87y-51143.6y^2+y(-10808.9+10808.9y)Log[y/(1.-1.y)]+(-10808.9+32426.6y-21617.7y^2)Log[1.-(1.y)/(1.-1.y)])/(-1.+y)

Show[
Plot[f1[x],{x,0,.75},PlotRange->All],
Plot[g1[y],{y,0,.75},PlotRange->All]
]

Chop[FindRoot[
{
(f1[x]-g1[y])/(x-y)==D[f1[x],x]==D[g1[y],y]
},
{x,0.0000001},{y,.00000001}
]
[[All,2]]
]
```

However, you'll notice from the plot that there exists another common tangent at slightly larger values of `x` and `y` (say `x` ~ 4 and `y` ~ 5). Now, interestingly if I slightly change the above expressions for `f1[x]` and `g1[y]` to something like the following:

```
    f2[x_]:=(7968.08-59377.8x+40298.7x^2+(-39909.6+93122.4x-53212.8x^2)Log[(1.-1.33333x)/(1.-1.x)]+x(-13303.2+13303.2x)Log[x/(1.-1.x)])/(-1.+x)
    g2[y_]:=(5805.16-27866.2y-21643.y^2+y(-13303.2+13303.2y)Log[y/(1.-1.y)]+(-13303.2+39909.6y-26606.4y^2)Log[1.-(1.y)/(1.-1.y)])/(-1.+y)

    Show[
    Plot[f2[x],{x,0,.75},PlotRange->All],
    Plot[g2[y],{y,0,.75},PlotRange->All]
    ]

    Chop[FindRoot[
    {
    (f2[x]-g2[y])/(x-y)==D[f2[x],x]==D[g2[y],y]
    },
    {x,0.0000001},{y,.00000001}
    ]
    [[All,2]]
    ]
```

And use the same method to determine the common tangent, Mathematica chooses to find the larger values of `x` and `y` for the positive sloping tangent.

Finally, my question: is it possible to have Mathematica find both the high and low `x` and `y` values for the common tangent and store these values in a similar way that allows me to make a list plot? The functions `f` and `g` above are all complex functions of another variable, `z`, and I am currently using something like the following to plot the tangent points (should be two `x` and two `y`) as a function of `z`.

```
ex[z_]:=Chop[FindRoot[
{
(f[x,z]-g[y,z])/(x-y)==D[f[x],x]==D[g[y],y]
},
{x,0.0000001},{y,.00000001}
]
[[All,2]]
]

ListLinePlot[
Table[{ex[z][[i]],z},{i,1,2},{z,1300,1800,10}]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

To find estimates for `{x, y}` that would solve your equations, you could plot them in `ContourPlot` and look for intersection points. For example

```
f1[x_]:=(5513.12-39931.8 x+23307.5 x^2+(-32426.6+75662. x- 
    43235.4 x^2)Log[(1.-1.33333 x)/(1.-1.x)]+
    x(-10808.9+10808.9 x) Log[x/(1.-1.x)])/(-1.+x)
g1[y_]:=(3632.71+3806.87 y-51143.6 y^2+y (-10808.9+10808.9y) Log[y/(1.-1.y)]+
    (-10808.9+32426.6 y-21617.7 y^2) Log[1.-(1.y)/(1.-1.y)])/(-1.+y)

plot = ContourPlot[{f1'[x] == g1'[y], f1[x] + f1'[x] (y - x) == g1[y]}, 
   {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see there are 2 intersection points in the interval `(0,1)`. You could then read off the points from the graph and use these as starting values for `FindRoot`:

```
seeds = {{.6,.4}, {.05, .1}};
sol = FindRoot[{f1'[x] == g1'[y], f1[x] + f1'[x] (y - x) == g1[y]}, 
    {x, #1}, {y, #2}] & @@@ seeds
```

To get the pairs of points from sol you can use `ReplaceAll`:

```
points = {{x, f1[x]}, {y, g1[y]}} /. sol

(* 
 ==> {{{0.572412, 19969.9}, {0.432651, 4206.74}}, 
      {{0.00840489, -5747.15}, {0.105801, -7386.68}}}
*)
```

To show that these are the correct points:

```
Show[Plot[{f1[x], g1[x]}, {x, 0, 1}],
 {ParametricPlot[#1 t + (1 - t) #2, {t, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Point[{##}]}]} & @@@ points]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

OK, so let's quickly rewrite what you've done so far:

Using your `f1` and `g1`, we have the plot

```
plot = Plot[{f1[x], g1[x]}, {x, 0, .75}]
```

[image: da plot]

and the first shared tangent at

```
sol1 = Chop[FindRoot[{(f1[x] - g1[y])/(x - y) == D[f1[x], x] == D[g1[y], y]}, 
    {x, 0.0000001}, {y, .00000001}]]

(* {x -> 0.00840489, y -> 0.105801} *)
```

Define the function

```
l1[t_] = (1 - t) {x, f1[x]} + t {y, g1[y]} /. sol1
```

then, you can plot the tangents using

```
Show[plot, Graphics[Point[{l1[0], l1[1]}]], 
     ParametricPlot[l1[t], {t, -1, 2}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-.2, .4}, {-10000, 10000}}]
```

[image: combined plot]

---

I briefly note (for my own sake) that the equations you used 
(e.g., to generate `sol1` above) 
come from requiring that the tangent line for `f1` at `x` 
tangentially hits `g1` at some point `y`, i.e.,

```
LogicalExpand[{x, f[x]} + t {1, f'[x]} == {y, g[y]} && f'[x] == g'[y]]
```

---

To investigate where the shared tangents lie, you can use a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[Show[plot, ParametricPlot[{x, f1[x]} + t {1, f1'[x]}, {t, -1, 1}]], 
       {x, 0, .75, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

which produces something like

[image: animation!]

Using the eyeballed values for `x` and `y`, you can get the actual solutions using

```
sol = Chop[Table[
   FindRoot[{(f1[x] - g1[y])/(x - y) == D[f1[x], x] == D[g1[y], y]},
    {x, xy[[1]]}, {y, xy[[2]]}], {xy, {{0.001, 0.01}, {0.577, 0.4}}}]]
```

define the two tangent lines using

```
l[t_] = (1 - t) {x, f1[x]} + t {y, g1[y]} /. sol
```

then

```
Show[plot, Graphics[Point[Flatten[{l[0], l[1]}, 1]]], 
 ParametricPlot[l[t], {t, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Dotted]]
```

[image: anudda plot]

---

This process could be automated, but I'm not sure how to do it efficiently.